# Error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, mariadb

El error que me retorna es:

> ```
> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '0) VALUES ('admin@hotmail.com', 'ASFKSFKFGA', 'Enviar',
> 'ASFKSFKFGA')' at line 1
>
> INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `contraseña`, `btn_enviar`, 0) VALUES
> ('admin@hotmail.com', 'ASFKSFKFGA', 'Enviar', 'ASFKSFKFGA')
>
> Filename:
> C:/xampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter-3.1.4/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691
> ```

---

En el modelo tengo lo siguiente:

```
function add_new_users()
{
     $this->load->database();//carga base de datos
     $data_insertar=$this->input->post();
     //unset($data_insertar['btn_enviar']);
    $this->db->insert('users',$data_insertar);
```

en el controlador lo siguiente:

```
public function add_user(){
    $this->load->helper('form');//helper para los formularios
    $this->load->library('form_validation');//cargar libreria de validaciones
    $this->load->model('User');
    if ($this->input->post()){//si ya hay datos cargados o se cargan
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email');//que los datos ingresados en el campo sean los necesarios del campo de la base de datos, validar que lo se que se requiere existe..
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contraseña','Contraseña','required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]');
        if  ($this->form_validation->run()== TRUE){ //si las validaciones pasan y corren!
            $this->User->add_new_users();
            print_r($this->input->post());//para mostrar ls datos
        }
        else {//si fallan las validaciones
            echo "Esta ingresando algo malo";
            $this->load->view('formulari'); //aca envia del nuevo al formulario
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('formulari');
        }
    }
```

---

y en la vista tengo:

```
<?php echo form_open() ?>
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="">
<?php echo form_error('email'); ?></br>
<?php echo form_label('Email','lblemail') ?> 
<?php echo form_input($input_email) ?> </br>
<?php echo form_error('contraseña');?></br>
<?php echo form_label('Contraseña','lblcontra') ?>
<?php echo form_password($password_contraseña) ?> </br>
<?php echo form_submit ('btn_enviar','Enviar') ?>
<div id="boton">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Enviar </button>
</div>
<?php echo form_close() ?>
```

Comment: Haz un `print_r`de `$data_insertar` antes del `db->insert` Y muestranos la estructura de la tabla `users`

Answer (score 1):

No puedes mandar 0 como el nombre de un campo de la tabla.

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `contraseña`, `btn_enviar`, 0)<--AQUI VALUES ('admin@hotmail.com', 'ASFKSFKFGA', 'Enviar', 'ASFKSFKFGA')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ten cuidado con esta función `this->input->post()`, porque las inserciones las hace en un orden distinto al que tienes pensado o configurado desde el formulario de envío o método de inserción.

La función

```
this->input->post()
```

recoge los parámetros del formulario dentro de un array asociativo desde el controlador y de su función `public function add_user(){}`

Sería así.

```
$datos = array(
    'input_email' => $this-input->get_post('input_email'),
    'password' => $this-input->get_post('password')
);
```